# Comments not in correct order by their names and timestamp firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server

The comment section of my application **is not working properly**, the childs are **mixing up** by their **names and the timestamp**, the content inside of them it is in **correct order**, here are **all of my code** inside Pastebin links (**if necessary** to see the whole code), also I provided the **chunks** I think that the problem is in.

**1) CommentAdapter.java Activity** (https://pastebin.com/m7LHDUDF)
Take note of this block of code:

```
private void getHandleName(final ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Log.d(TAG, "getHandleName: checking comment userID" + viewHolder.comment.getUser_id());
    Query query;
    query = reference
            .child("data")
            .child("-Kxzyb5JsUPhsMQAb84X")
            .child("users")
            .orderByChild("user_id")
            .equalTo(viewHolder.comment.getUser_id());

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                viewHolder.handleName.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getHandlename());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**2) CommentRecylerViewAdapter** (https://pastebin.com/Tb7L9EVD)

```
 private void getHandleName(final CommentViewHolder viewHolder, Comment comment) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Log.d(TAG, "getHandleName: checking comment userID" + comment.getUser_id());
    Query query = reference
            .child("data")
            .child("-Kxzyb5JsUPhsMQAb84X")
            .child("users")
            .orderByChild("user_id")
            .equalTo(comment.getUser_id());


    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                viewHolder.handleName.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getHandlename());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**3)Chunk of code for adding the comment:**
` private void addComment() {

```
    if (commentText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(ViewPostActivity.this, "Please enter your comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        String commentID = reference.push().getKey();

        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setCaption(commentText.getText().toString());
        comment.setDate_created(System.currentTimeMillis());
        comment.setUser_id(currentUserID);

        reference.child("data").child("-Kxzyb5JsUPhsMQAb84X").child("comments").child(postID).child(commentID).setValue(comment);
        setNumComment();
        setNumPointCurrentUser();
        setNumPointUser();
        setNumPointPost();
    }
}`
```

**4) **And Finally, the c**omment model Activity** which I think is ok(https://pastebin.com/VaYV3Gv3)

Here is a screenshot of my **database**:

1. `-Kxzyb5JsUPhsMQAb84X` is the root of my database
2. comments is where all the comments are store per post
3. -`LSv6lXZml-Cf0GX3i5q` randomly generated child that stores the other content such as Timestamps,user id and content

[image: Database]

Here is the screenshot of my phone showing the **incorrect** order of the comments:

[image: Phone Screenshot]

Comment: There's also a `-LSym...` key in the tree, which I assume is the comment ID. There's no way for Firebase to order child nodes over double nested dynamic keys. What you pass into `orderByChild()` must exist at a fixed path under each child node of the location you query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So I am afraid that this can't be solved, any suggestion that will help me with this headache or point out a another way of handling comments.

Comment: Firebase Database searches across a list of child nodes. Right now you have a tree, which it can't search across. If you want to search across all comments to all posts, you need to have a non-nested list of all comments.